# Need to get the selected item from Multiple select listbox in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, listbox

I use the Following Code for Bind the values in Multiple select Listbox with Check box in silverlight

```
  <ListBox x:Name="ValListBox" Margin="188,212,136,100" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I need to get the selected item text using c#?

Comment: If you want it ViewModel you can get it by Binding SelectedItem of ListBox to a property of same type as of ItemsSource Collection . If you want it in xaml then you can Bind SelectedItem.Content property and ElementName  ValListBox

Answer (score 0):

By Using the Following Method We can get the Selected Item in multiselect Listbox.

Changes in xaml: We need to add Click Function.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ValListBox" Margin="188,212,136,100" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox   Click="CheckBox_Click" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}"  Content="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

In Code Behind We can get like,

```
List<string> selecteditems = new List<string>();
 private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cb = sender as CheckBox;
            if (cb.IsChecked == true)
            {
                var item = cb.DataContext;
                selecteditems.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                var item = cb.DataContext;
                selecteditems.Remove(item.ToString());
            }
        }
```

In selecteditems List we can get the all selected items from Multiple Listbox